# order of execution mixed up with use of Thread.sleep

Tags: java, android, sleep, thread-sleep

I am writing a method for my android app where I make a RecyclerView invisible, and a ProgressBar visible. I then perform some logic, before resetting the two views to their original visibility state.

With just the `setVisibility()` call, it works as intended. However, I am also required to call `Thread.sleep()` to force a wait directly after performing the logic.

Initially, I have had trouble trying to call `setVisibility()` to begin with. It simply did nothing. I have found many questions with similar problems, but not similar enough; I was unable to find a solution specific to my problem.

Creating a new method to simply call `setVisibility()`, I found that this worked as intended. I started to move my logic over, line by line, until it stopped working.

As it stands, it still *technically* sets the visibility correctly. However, despite being several lines down from the `setVisibility()` calls, my `Thread.sleep()` seems to be forcing itself to run before `setVisibility()`. I believe this was my original problem; Logically, the commands after `Thread.sleep()` would run directly after, and effectivley undo my `setVisibility()` on the very next frame.

This is my method:

```
public void SetMainInvisible(){
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mMainProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mTrainAdapter.RefreshAll();

    Log.d("TEST", "FINISHED VIS");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(sSleepTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        // In the nature of a simple "Thread.sleep", there is no real reason to respond
        // directly to interruption. If the sleep request is interrupted, the best course
        // of action to preserve user experience is to simply move on. That said, we will
        // still "re-enable" the flag that tells us the thread was interrupted, in case we
        // should need to clarify if there was an interruption, later on. As is, this flag
        // will be reset to false as soon as the exception is thrown.
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

From my direct observation, when it calls, my log prints "FINISHED VIS". My application then enters the `Thread.sleep()` stage, and waits for 3 seconds. My views then change their visibility, **as directed by the very first lines**. I do not have `setVisibility()` anywhere else in my code.

I have tried reading further on Thread.sleep, but all references suggest exactly what I have been taught; when it executes, it forces the process to "sleep" for a set period of time. It should not force the method to postpone all other logic until it returns. On the contrary, [the examples at Tutorial Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_sleep_millis.htm) provide logic and output that suggests normal operation.

I know that I should never really be calling `Thread.sleep()`, but it is a direct requirement of the exercise I am completing for University. Why is `Thread.sleep()` forcing itself to run before any other command, despite being at the ***end*** of the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing visibility (or any other layout/drawing operation) does not have any immediate, synchronous effect on your user interface. Instead, essentially just a message is posted on the UI thread's message queue to take care of the change later.

Calling `sleep()` on the UI thread is a no-no. You're blocking the UI thread and execution does not return to the message handler that would take care of the relayout/redraw messages waiting in the queue. Only after the `sleep()` does the execution return to the message handler.

If you need to add delays to your code, use e.g. `Handler#postDelayed()` to post a `Runnable` of your own to the UI thread's message queue to be executed after a delay.

Comment: Cheers. To be perfectly honest, I am completely ignorant to `Handler#postDelayed()`, however I understood the rest of it, and have managed to fix my problem with an alternate implementation much quicker than I would have been able to learn how to properly implement your suggestion. +1 for setting me in the right direction, much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

Working off @laalto's answer, I decided to test my method in the form of an `AsyncTask`, before looking into `Handler#postDelayed()` (This is something we have not covered, and I am completely unfamiliar with it). I am happy to report that it works exactly as intended.

This might be a suitable alternative, for those that are more familiar with implementing `AsyncTask`.

First, I implement an inner asynchronous class as follows:

```
private class RefreshTimesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private long mSleepTime;
    public RefreshTimesAsyncTask (long sleepTime) {
        mSleepTime = sleepTime;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mMainProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mTrainAdapter.RefreshAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(mSleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            // ...
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mMainProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I then simply call `new RefreshTimesAsyncTask(sSleepTime).execute();`, rather than my previous function call of `SetMainInvisible()`. I also set `static long sSleepTime=3000` in the variable declaration of my main class, due to the nature of being required to set this value as a `static`, and ***not*** being able to declare `static` variables in an inner class.